# Re-using QRunnable

Tags: multithreading, qt, pyqt, threadpool

I have been experimenting with `QRunnable` in order to get some service calls up and running. I have stumbled across the following piece of information from the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthreadpool.html#tryStart):

> QThreadPool supports executing the same QRunnable more than once by
>   calling tryStart(this) from within QRunnable::run(). If autoDelete is
>   enabled the QRunnable will be deleted when the last thread exits the
>   run function. Calling start() multiple times with the same QRunnable
>   when autoDelete is enabled creates a race condition and is not
>   recommended.

**Can someone explain what this means?** I've written the following code and it allows me to execute a `QRunnable` object multiple times sequentially:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from PyQt4.QtCore import QRunnable, pyqtSlot, pyqtSignal, QObject, QThread, QThreadPool
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QLabel
from sys import exit, argv
from random import getrandbits

class ServiceCallSignals(QObject):
  srv_status = pyqtSignal(bool)
  srv_running = pyqtSignal(bool)

class ServiceCall(QRunnable):

  def __init__(self):
    super(ServiceCall, self).__init__()
    self.signals = ServiceCallSignals()

  def run(self):
    self.signals.srv_running.emit(True)
    call = bool(getrandbits(1))
    print('QRunnable Thread ID: %d' % int(QThread.currentThreadId()))
    if call: QThread.sleep(5)

    self.signals.srv_status.emit(call)
    self.signals.srv_running.emit(False)

class Test(QWidget):

  def __init__(self):
    super(Test, self).__init__()
    self.initUI()

  def initUI(self):

    layout = QHBoxLayout(self)

    self.cb = QPushButton('Send request', self)
    self.cb.clicked.connect(self.srv_send)
    layout.addWidget(self.cb)

    self.lbl = QLabel('Waiting...', self)
    layout.addWidget(self.lbl)

    self.srv = ServiceCall()
    self.srv.setAutoDelete(False)
    self.srv.signals.srv_status.connect(self.srv_receive)
    self.srv.signals.srv_running.connect(self.srv_block)
    self.tp = QThreadPool(self)

    self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
    self.setWindowTitle('QRunnable and ROS service calls')
    self.show()

  @pyqtSlot()
  def srv_send(self):
    print('Main Thread ID: %d' % int(QThread.currentThreadId()))
    self.tp.start(self.srv)
    self.cb.setText('Running for reply')

  @pyqtSlot(bool)
  def srv_block(self, state):
    self.cb.setEnabled(not state)

  @pyqtSlot(bool)
  def srv_receive(self, srv_res):
    if srv_res: self.lbl.setText('Success')
    else: self.lbl.setText('Failed')
    self.cb.setText('Send request')

def main():

  app = QApplication(argv)
  t = Test()
  exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

**Does the quote from the documentation mean that I'm doing it wrong?** If I put my `QThreadPool` and use `tryStart(self)` inside my run I get many, many threads running...

Comment: But you have `autoDelete` disabled: so what don't you understand?

Comment: The documentation says that `tryStart()` should be put inside the `run()` of the `QRunnable`, which is not how I am doing it here (see last sentence of my post what happens when I put `tryStart(self)` inside my `run()`).

Comment: I think you're misinterpreting it - see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is saying that it *supports* calling `tryStart` inside `run()`, not that it is *required*.

If you sequentially call `start()` outside of `run()` it will re-use the same thread. But if you call `tryStart()` within `run()` it may reserve additional threads if necessary.

Comment: Ah, indeed I have misinterpreted the documentation. Thanks! I'm glad my code is actually correct. LOL

Comment: > If you sequentially call start() outside of run() it will re-use the same thread. 
i doubt that, since start will look for an active thread, or puts into queue if no active thread is available. `Reserves a thread and uses it to run runnable, unless this thread will make the current thread count exceed maxThreadCount(). In that case, runnable is added to a run queue instead.`  source: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qthreadpool.html#start

Answer (score 0):

you need to `.setAutoDelete(0)` in order to use `trystart()`.
`Autodelete(0)` means that after execution of a thread it wont be deleted automatically and you should delete it manually when you want.

then when launching/ relaunching the thread by using `trystart()` instead of `start()` a race condition is avoided, as the same thread continues.
it's on the documentation.
good luck