How to run the same QRunnable in a QThreadPool multiple times?
I'm reading the french book "Maîtrisez Qt 5: guide de développement d'applications professionnelles" to learn Qt.
There is a small code in it to explain QThreadPool :
#include "MaTache.h"
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QThreadPool>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QThreadPool::globalInstance()->setMaxThreadCount(3);

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
        MaTache *t = new MaTache; // MaTache inherits from QRunnable
        QThreadPool::globalInstance()->start(t);
    }
    
    QThreadPool::globalInstance()->waitForDone();

    return 0;
}

However, I read this advice in the official QT documentation :

Calling QThreadPool::start() multiple times with the same QRunnable
when autoDelete is enabled creates a race condition and is not
recommended.

Also, I read in the official documentation about QThreadPool::waitForDone(QDeadlineTimer deadline = QDeadlineTimer::Forever) :

Waits until deadline expires for all threads to exit and removes all
threads from the thread pool. Returns true if all threads were
removed; otherwise it returns false.

So, I have a few questions :

When the advice says "the same QRunnable", is that the same class or the same instance of the class ? Here we use the same class but not the same instance, so is there a race condition ?
If we add t->setAutoDelete(false); (because it is true by default) just before the call to start, how do we manually delete the QRunnable ?
The previous question talks about the deletion of the QRunnable, QThreadPool::waitForDone will rather delete the threads, can I use it indifferently depending on the QRunnable deletion mode?


Does this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/35560739/1741542 help?

@OlafDietsche I read it before posting, it use 'self.srv.setAutoDelete(False)' but I don't have enough experience with Python to understand how it manually delete the QRunnable.. Furthermore, it doesn't answer all my questions.


It refers to the same instance -- i.e. the same object.  Note, however that it's up to you to make sure that multiple instances of your own derived class can be invoked on different threads without invoking race conditions . 2) You manage the lifetime of a QRunnable the same way you would any other variable.  3)  Sorry, but I really don't understand the question.  Also note that your post would benefit from one or more use-cases that serve to outline your concerns.


@kingsjester for 2) at the end of the runnable you emit a signal with, and whoever is listening on this signal will get the result and delete the runnable.

(1) obviously refers to instances, since it's the instance functions that are being run; (3) threads are not "deleted" (at least, not *directly" from Qt): threading classes are interfaces to the OS threading management.

here there is a new instance at each iteration of the loop... Does this imply that i'm not in the race condition situation described in the excerpt from the documentation cited above?

@kingsjester A race condition only happens whenever any of the involving parts tries to access the same object and that object is not considered/declared as thread safe (or is not made safe, eg: without using semaphores, locks, etc.). If you have a QRunnable class A that, in its run(), tries to access a common object X, then you get a race condition if X is not thread safe, because a and b (instances of A) are trying to access (read/write/delete) X. If each instance of A creates its own separate Y object considering aspects based on X, then it should be safe.

@kingsjester The concept is actually relatively simple to get, at least in theory: multi threading allows accessing the same memory space (and, therefore, pointers to objects living in that space) at different moments, possibly concurrently and unexpectedly. Leaving out the fact that some objects should only be accessed by a specific thread (eg: UI elements from the main thread), a race condition results in an inconsistent state depending on when the same object (normally, an instance) is accessed at the "same" time: in some cases, that object could not even exist anymore.

Here are the three answers, from the comments of the question and this part of the documentation :

Note that the thread pool takes ownership of the runnable if
runnable->autoDelete() returns true, and the runnable will be deleted
automatically by the thread pool after the runnable->run() returns. If
runnable->autoDelete() returns false, ownership of runnable remains
with the caller.


The advice of the documentation, talking about a a race condition when calling QThreadPool::start() multiple times with the same QRunnable (when autoDelete is enabled) is just about the possibility of a double-deletion of the same instance of a QRunnable. In this example we never call QThreadPool::start with the same instance so there is no race condition.

If we add  t->setAutoDelete(false);  (which is true by default) just before the call to start, we can manually delete the  QRunnable after by keeping the adress and calling delete after QThreadPool::globalInstance()->waitForDone();.

Since QThreadPool::waitForDone will rather delete the threads than the QRunnable, it can be used indifferently on the QRunnable deletion mode (with/without auto-delete).


